# Is terminal overflowing bad?

Tags: command-line

If you do something in terminal, like `ping google.com` and let it run for hours for example, can that like cause errors because it printed it so long? Like an overflow...

Comment: No.............

Comment: lit :)................................

Comment: Most terminal applications have limited buffer that can be set - for instance 2000 lines. Anything past that will be gone.

Comment: Every computation your hardware does consumes energy and causes it to degenerate a little more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The terminal can keep displaying output for as long as you need without any negative effects on performance.